# Why does changing my margin percentage mess with the spacing of my custom buttons?

Tags: react-native, user-interface, expo

I'm new to React-Native and web development, but I do have a smidge of CSS experience. I've come across an issue that I can't figure out and I haven't found anything online that expresses a similar problem so that I may figure out why this is happening.

I have custom hexagonal buttons that I want to space out in a similar fashion to an onscreen keyboard which I have done, but my buttons are a bit too far up. The first row is obscured by the notification bar. My StyleSheet for my rows look like this:

```js
const style = StyleSheet.create({
   screen: {
     width: '100%',
     height: '100%',
     backgroundColor: '#lele19'
   },
   firstRow: {
     alignItems: 'center',
     justifyContent: 'space-between',
     flexDirection: 'row',
     paddingTop: '5%',
     marginHorizontal: '5%'
   }
   row: {
     alignItems: 'center',
     justifyContent: 'space-between',
     flexDirection: 'row',
     marginHorizontal: '5%'
   }
});
```

Each "row" of buttons is within a `View` component.

So to try to fix the position so that the notification bar was not in the way I changed my `paddingTop:` from 5% to 15% and as a result, it seems to move my row down as I want, but now the space between my buttons is increased as seen from this screenshot: [image: phone screenshot with the first button of each row being in the correct place, but each button after has a large space in between.]

It seems that any padding I do that is past 5% causes the spacing of my buttons to be off. How can I prevent this? What am I doing wrong? It appears this way on any device whether it is a phone or a tablet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Since people are asking for more here is my PortraitLayout.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import HexButton from './HexagonButton';

const PortraitLayout = props => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <View style={styles.firstRow}>
                <HexButton>a</HexButton>
                <HexButton>b</HexButton>
                <HexButton>c</HexButton>
                <HexButton>d</HexButton>
                <HexButton>e</HexButton>
                <HexButton>f</HexButton>
                <HexButton>g</HexButton>
                <HexButton>h</HexButton>
                <HexButton>i</HexButton>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <HexButton>j</HexButton>
                <HexButton>k</HexButton>
                <HexButton>l</HexButton>
                <HexButton>m</HexButton>
                <HexButton>n</HexButton>
                <HexButton>o</HexButton>
                <HexButton>p</HexButton>
                <HexButton>q</HexButton>
                <HexButton>r</HexButton>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <HexButton>s</HexButton>
                <HexButton>t</HexButton>
                <HexButton>u</HexButton>
                <HexButton>v</HexButton>
                <HexButton>w</HexButton>
                <HexButton>x</HexButton>
                <HexButton>y</HexButton>
                <HexButton>z</HexButton>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#1e1e19'
    },
    firstRow: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingTop: '5%',
        marginHorizontal: '5%'
    },
    row: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingTop: '5%',
        marginHorizontal: '5%'
    }
});

export default PortraitLayout;
```

HexagonButton.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const HexagonButton = props => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.hexagon}>
                <View style={styles.hexagonInner}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{props.children}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.hexagonBefore} />
                <View style={styles.hexagonAfter} />
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

let buttonWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width / 11; //Make enough room for 16 even though I am only putting 13 per row.
let buttonHeight = buttonWidth * 0.55;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    hexagon: {
        width: buttonWidth,
        height: buttonHeight
    },
    hexagonInner: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#ffec33',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    hexagonAfter: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: -1 * (buttonHeight * 0.45),
        left: 0,
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderLeftWidth: buttonWidth * 0.5,
        borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
        borderRightWidth: buttonWidth * 0.5,
        borderRightColor: 'transparent',
        borderTopWidth: buttonHeight * 0.45,
        borderTopColor: '#ffec33'
    },
    hexagonBefore: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: -1 * (buttonHeight * 0.45),
        left: 0,
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderLeftWidth: buttonWidth * 0.5,
        borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
        borderRightWidth: buttonWidth * 0.5,
        borderRightColor: 'transparent',
        borderBottomWidth: buttonHeight * 0.45,
        borderBottomColor: '#ffec23'
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 18
    }
});


export default HexagonButton;
```

and App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

import LandscapeLayout from './components/LandscapeLayout';
import PortraitLayout from './components/PortraitLayout';

export default function App() {
  return (
   <PortraitLayout/>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});
```

That is literally all of the code I have. I hope this will paint a better picture of the issue. I will try the borders thing and see what that yields.

EDIT: 
Here is the result of the border color test. It looks like my buttons extend past the border. For simplicity, I only changed the top row so that the buttons were spaced incorrectly. Also for the sake of testing I added another style to the Portrait.js file that is just a copy of `row`.

[image: 3 rows of letters surrounded by borders of various colors. the first row is spaced incorrectly.]

Comment: Is this all of your StyleSheet?

Comment: This is all my StyleSheet that I use for aligning the buttons on the screen.

Comment: Try to add borders to all you containers to see which one is exceeding your main screen. I usually work it from there. I would like to see your html as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why it happens but I did manage to fix it. It had something to do with `justifyContent` and the fact that my button rows were not within a new of their own. I added a view around my button rows like this:

```js
  <View style={styles.screen}>
        <View style={styles.keyboardLayout}>
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <HexButton>a</HexButton>
                <HexButton>b</HexButton>
                <HexButton>c</HexButton>
                <HexButton>d</HexButton>
                <HexButton>e</HexButton>
                <HexButton>f</HexButton>
                <HexButton>g</HexButton>
                <HexButton>h</HexButton>
                <HexButton>i</HexButton>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <HexButton>j</HexButton>
                <HexButton>k</HexButton>
                <HexButton>l</HexButton>
                <HexButton>m</HexButton>
                <HexButton>n</HexButton>
                <HexButton>o</HexButton>
                <HexButton>p</HexButton>
                <HexButton>q</HexButton>
                <HexButton>r</HexButton>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <HexButton>s</HexButton>
                <HexButton>t</HexButton>
                <HexButton>u</HexButton>
                <HexButton>v</HexButton>
                <HexButton>w</HexButton>
                <HexButton>x</HexButton>
                <HexButton>y</HexButton>
                <HexButton>z</HexButton>
            </View>
      </View>
</View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#1e1e19'
    },
    row: {
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingTop: '5%',
        marginHorizontal: '5%'
    },
    keyboardLayout: {
        height: '50%',
        width: '100%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
    }
});
```

I would still like to know the exact cause, but for now, my problem has been solved.